# Apply an R function to one dataset multiple times, but change the value of one argument each time

Tags: r, list, lapply

I want to write/apply a function that repeats the `LD2` function from the `pegas` package on a dataset (jaguar), but changes the value of the 'locus' argument each time. The 'locus' argument accepts a vector of length two (e.g. c(1,2), c(2,3), c(77,78), etc.).

For example, I want the code to run `loci.pairs[[1]]`, then `loci.pairs[[2]]`, loci.pairs[[3]], etc. and output the results as a list.

I have tried doing this with `lapply`, for loops and while loops but have run into errors (see below):

**Load libraries and data**

```
library(adegenet)
library(pegas)
data("jaguar")
```

**Create a list of pairs of loci**

```
loci.pairs = combn(seq(1,ncol(jaguar)-1), 2, simplify = FALSE)
loci.pairs[[1]]
```

**Compare each pair of loci from loci.pairs list**

```
LD2(jaguar, locus=c(1,2), details=FALSE)
LD2(jaguar, locus=loci.pairs[[1]], details=FALSE)
LD2(jaguar, locus=loci.pairs[[2]], details=FALSE)
LD2(jaguar, locus=loci.pairs[[3]], details=FALSE)
LD2(jaguar, locus=loci.pairs[[4]], details=FALSE)
LD2(jaguar, locus=loci.pairs[[78]], details=FALSE)
```

**lapply (error)**

```
lapply(jaguar, function(x) LD2(jaguar, locus=loci.pairs[[x]], details=FALSE))
```

> Error in loci.pairs[[x]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

Comment: you could maybe try `sapply(1:number_of_pairs,function(x) LD2(jaguar,locus=loci.pairs[[x]],details=FALSE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `lapply` function has a different syntax. Try this:

```
lapply(loci.pairs, function(x) LD2(jaguar, locus=x, details=FALSE))
```

The first argument of `lapply` contains the list which you want to iterate over.
Since you want to iterate over the combinations you have to use `lapply(loci.pairs...)` instead of `lapply(jaguar,...)`.

Essentially, this call to `lapply` is (in terms of output) equivalent to the following loop:

```
result_list = list()
for (i in 1:n) {
   result_list[[i]] <-  LD2(jaguar, locus=loci.pairs[[i]], details=FALSE)
}
```